# Error using @ngx-translate/core with Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular5

I get the following error when I try to use the `@ngx-translate/core` app on my Angular App (running v5) with Visual Studio 2017 SPA template.

`aspnet-prerendering` is turned off on the app i.e. so the index.cshtml is;

`<app>Loading...</app>`

I have followed the following link as a guide for adding the translation services (along with the official guide);

[ngx-translate tutorial](https://medium.com/letsboot/translate-angular-4-apps-with-ngx-translate-83302fb6c10d)

So I have the following in my package.json (all Angular references are ^5.0.0);

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
```

Then I have the following in my app.browser.module.ts;

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/Public/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        AppModuleShared
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl }
    ]
})
```

In my app.component.ts I have;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    }

    switchLanguage(language: string) {
        this.translate.use(language);
    }
}
```

and finally I call my translation in my component;

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hero',
    templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})
export class HeroComponent {
    constructor(translate: TranslateService) {

    }
}
```

where in the hero.component.html I have `{{ 'Hero.Intro' | translate }}`.

However, when I run I get the following error;

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("<div class="hero mh-100">
    <h1 class="display-4"> {{ [ERROR ->]'Hero.Intro' | translate }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app.module.ts** (Angular 5.2)

create factory:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

use in TranslateModule

```
imports: [
  //imports
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
     provide: TranslateLoader,
     useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
     deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  })
]
```

and files in /src/assets/i18n/

**en.json**

**ru.json**

structure of **en.json** file

```
{
  "phrase1": "Hello",
  "phrase2": "World"
}
```

**ru.json** file

```
{
  "phrase1": "Привет",
  "phrase2": "Мир"
}
```

in **app.component.ts** constructor, service must be public:

```
constructor(public translate: TranslateService){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.translate.addLangs(["en", "ru"]);
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    let browserLang = this.translate.getBrowserLang();
    if (browserLang.match( /ru/ )) {
      this.translate.use( 'ru' );
    }
    else if (browserLang.match( /en/ )) {
      this.translate.use( 'en' );
    } else {
      this.translate.use( 'en' );
    }
}
```

in template:

```
<p>{{ 'phrase1' | translate }}</p>
<p>{{ 'phrase2' | translate }}</p>
```

Comment: I have tried to modifying from `private` to `public` in the app.component.ts but I still get the same error?

Comment: try change in HeroComponent

Comment: Yes it is here too. I have also tried moving the `{{ Hero.Intro | translate }}` tot he app.component.ts and .html too and i get the same error

Comment: can you provide your json?

Comment: maybe, you not have a json object Hero with property Intro, and you can change from {{ 'Hero.Intro' | translate }} to {{ 'Intro' | translate }}

Comment: no that didnt make a difference? still the same? just to clirfy the Hero.Text exists in all three (fr, pt and en).

Comment: `{
  "HomePage": {
    "Title": "2 Translation example",
    "Intro": "2 Hello I am Arthur, I am 42 years old."
  },
  "Hero": {
    "Intro": "Helping you find the right trade or service."
  }` is the json just FYI

Comment: also out of interest if I remove all references to the `{{ Hero.Intro | translate }}` (i.e. so I am not translating anything, but maintain the references everywhere else (i.e. in app.browser.module.ts, app.component.ts etc) the error does not occur. I have also tried giving it a falsy path to the json to make sure its finding it, and it does indeed give a file not found error in this case, so the json files are being read too.